# Metamask signature request with empty message

Tags: signature, decentralized-exchange

Can someone help me to understand these empty signature requests?

For example using the Plutus Dex when clicking to stake your plu you got this:
[image: plutus dex example]

What does this mean? And what harm this can cause? And if you sign some message like this can you "unsign"?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cant unsign once you have signed . Almost every dApp on blockchain requires signature which means that user is giving blockchain permission to store its data which is its signature which can be used by the dApp in further functionality or to identify different users on their dApp. You should be careful when signing such messages and also ensure that the source is reliable or not.